# Show full trace of errors during mvn test

Tags: java, maven, junit

When I run Junit tests `mvn test` it gives me the following trace for a given error:

```
InvalidEmailTest.setUp:45->BasicTest.getAssertedSubElement:461 » StaleElementReference
```

So it shows me the entry point method and the method where the exception occurred. Is it possible to see the same thing with every function called in between? That would make debugging a lot easier

What it makes my call trace look like:

```
* InvalidEmailTest.setUp
  * BasicTest.getAssertSubElement
```

What it actually is:

```
* InvalidEmailTest.setUp
  * cHelper.accessSpecificGestion
     * mHelper.goTab
         * mHelper.accessOffice
             * BasicTest.getFirstChildByText
                 * BasicTest.getAssertSubElement
```

Is there a way to see on which line of each the exception occurred so I can pinpoint exactly where the error occurs in the `mvn test` results?

Comment: try `mvn test --info`

Comment: You should configure the property `<trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>` ...see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#trimStackTrace

Answer (score 1):

As @khmarbaise mentioned, you can configure the [`trimStackTrace`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#trimStackTrace) property to `false` in the [maven surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html). Your `build` section will look like:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <!-- Others plugins declaration -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Also if you like you could control the behavior via command line:

You could declare a property:

```
<properties>
  <!-- Others properties declaration -->
  <trimStackTrace>true</trimStackTrace>
</properties>
```

And controlling the plugin with it:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <trimStackTrace>${trimStackTrace}</trimStackTrace>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then if you run the `mvn test`, you will get the default trimmed output, or if you run the `mvn test -DtrimStackTrace=false`, you will get the output with the details.

Comment: Don't try to exclude a kind of integration test from surefire cause that's not the default of maven-surefire-plugin. It will never execute tests named like `*IntegrationTest.java`...so the above configuration is useless.

Comment: @khmarbaise I deleted that entry, I added it by mistake. In this case, only is needed the `trimStackTrace` as you suggested.